# How to put a password in PDF by Batch

Tags: vb.net, pdf

Is there any tools or DLL that can put a password in the PDF?

Example I have 1,000 PDF files I want to put a password on each PDF? The password will be different on each file.

-Regards,
Ryl

Answer (score 0):

Using Gnostice PDFOne .NET you can do this.

Just go through the article link given below.
http://www.gnostice.com/goto.asp?id=28504&t=encrypt_documents_using_gnostice_pdfone_.net

Disclaimer: I work for Gnostice.

Answer (score 0):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can be used to protect PDF files with password.

Here is a sample code for your task:

```
Dim filesToProcess As String()
' populate filesToProcess somehow

For Each fileName As String In filesToProcess
    Using pdf As New PdfDocument(fileName)
        ' use OwnerPassword property if you need to protect file from being modified 
        ' use UserPassword property if you need to protect file from being modified and from being viewed without knowing the password
        pdf.UserPassword = "password"
        
        ' there is also another supported encryption algorithms
        pdf.Encryption = PdfEncryptionAlgorithm.Aes128Bit

        Dim savePath As String = fileName & "encrypted.pdf"
        pdf.Save(savePath)
    End Using
Next
```

You can also [setup permissions](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Security/Permissions) for any protected PDF file.

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.